# Generate planet like heightmaps

Tags: software-engineering, procedural-generation

I would like to procedurally generate planets, but I don't know how to wrap a heightmap around a sphere. I already know how to generate plane heightmaps, but not how to generate spherical ones. Can someone push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically the strategy is not to produce a spherical height map, but instead to produce a normal height-map and wrap it around a sphere. You can find [some questions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/45167/square-game-map-rendered-as-sphere) on the site already about [this process](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/21232/generating-spherical-world-from-heightmapped-terrain).

There are a number of strategies for doing this, some of them as simple as mapping the Cartesian coordinates to spherical coordinates, or [warping the 6 faces](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/61345/constructing-a-planetoid-cube-world) of a [cube into a sphere](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/43741/how-do-you-turn-a-cube-into-a-sphere) ([similar to this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46691/spherical-procedural-terrain-shader-based-on-slope)). There are plenty of [ways to represent](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/56231/spherical-map-representation) your map.

Care needs to be taken to ensure your height-map properly wraps so that the terrain meets up where your height-map touches itself. [Creating tileable noise](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23625/how-do-you-generate-tileable-perlin-noise) is a start, but you can also use techniques like the [diamond square algorithm](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/37389/diamond-square-terrain-generation-problem) to easily generate wrapped noise.